# Is there a way in AnyLogic to have agent links displayed in a GIS Map?

Tags: anylogic

I created two agents with a link between them. The link element is set to draw lines between each two connected agents. However, the link shapes (i.e. lines) do not appear if the agents are placed on a GIS map.

Is there a quick workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative to using links.

I tried to dynamically create GIS Routes between the connected agents. It's not as simple as ticking a box, but it works. The code would look something like this:

```
GISMarkupSegmentLine L = new GISMarkupSegmentLine( 30, 80, 32, 85) ;
GISRoute R = new GISRoute(map, L);
```

Instead of the numbers 30, 80, etc., you would use the two agents' lon and lat

Comment: I find it better to use a gisRegion to create lines between agents :)

Comment: What is the advantage of region over route in this situation?

Comment: the route might mess up with your vehicle routing maybe'

Comment: Ah I see. In my cases, the question started as a replacement for agent links, so it is purely for presentation purposes.